# The meaning of 'a powder blue nothing' here

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

From The Apprenticeship of Duddy Kravitz by Mordecai Richler:

> Ida had just emerged from her bath and she sat ***in a powder blue
>   nothing*** before a mirror at a little table crammed with jars. The
>   mirror had an elaborate white frame with armed cupid carved into each
>   corner.

I can understand 'she sat before a mirror' part but what is the bold part? Is she wearing some kind of a powder blue gown? Then, what does 'nothing' here mean?

Comment: sounds like a négligée / negligee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you. *Nothing* can sometimes be used when something is insignificant, as opposed to literally "nonexistent". In this case, it suggests that she was wearing very little clothing—"practically nothing". If we assume it's a gown, then it was very revealing.

---

Edit: I was thinking of flimsy, sheer ***night**  gown* when I wrote *gown* above. But as @Tᴚoɯɐuo points out, it might be more accurate to call it a *negligee*.

> The [negligee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligee) [...] is a form of see-through clothing for women consisting of a sheer usually long dressing gown.It is a form of nightgown intended for wear at night and in the bedroom.
>   [image]
>   (Wikipedia)